# refresh squid rules after every change

Tags: squid

I have squid proxy server running on ubuntu.
I wrote set of rules for acl including something like:

```
acl exceeded_users proxy_auth "/etc/squid/users/exceeded"
http_access deny exceeded_users all_dst
```

if any user exceed the bandwidth limit then his name will transfer to exceeded list.
but the problem is to apply this change i need to restart squid.
Is there any way to apply like these changes automatically without restarting squid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Running `squid -k reconfigure` will cause it to reload the configuration without restarting.

You can use [incron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man5/incrontab.5.html) to monitor your `/etc/squid/users/exceeded` list to automatically trigger the reconfigure command whenever that file is written to.